# RollupSummary Child records to the Parent record that are the same object

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have a custom object (Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c) where I want to roll-up child records to it's parent record.  Since this is on the same object, it cannot be a rollup summary field and has to be a trigger.  I have started writing a trigger but could use some assistance to complete it.  Its fairly simple what it needs to do, which is to roll-up agreement records that have status not equal to approved and has a parent record associated to it or not null.  I will post the trigger and class in the answer below.  Appreciate any assistance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

//Trigger
trigger ApttusChildRollup on Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c (after update,after insert) {

```
if (TriggerContextUtility.isFirstRun()) {

System.debug (logginglevel.DEBUG, '@@@@@@@@ Step 1');

//Loop through all the Agreements that caused the trigger and add their associated IDs to a Set

set<Id> AgreementIds = new set<Id>();

for (integer i=0;i<trigger.size;i++)
{
    if((Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)  && trigger.new[i].Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c!= null
       && trigger.new[i].Pricing_Approval_Status__c <> 'Approved')
    {
        AgreementIds.add(trigger.new[i].ID);
    }


}
RollupChildAgreements.ChildAgreements(AgreementIds);
}
```

}

//Class
public without sharing class RollupChildAgreements {

```
public static void ChildAgreements(set<Id> AgreementIds)
```

{
    list AgreementsTobeUpdated = new list();
    list ParentAgreements = [select Pricing_Approval_Status__c from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c where Id in :Agreementids];

```
System.debug('Method called with:@@@@@@@' + agreementids +'Step 1');

integer i=0;     

For (Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agmt : ParentAgreements){          

        //agmt.Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c == ParentAgreements.Id    

                i = i+1; 

                System.debug('Method called with:@@@@@@@' + agreementids +'Step 2');

    agmt.Total_Child_Agreement__c = i;
    AgreementsTobeUpdated.add(agmt);
}        
 if(!AgreementsTobeUpdated.isEmpty())
 {
     update AgreementsTobeUpdated;
 }
```

}
}

Comment: Hi @sfdev
i will prefer to use below apps to reduce my development time:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I installed but the helper is not going to work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), a tool providing the Rollup Summary functionality (usually available only on Master-Detail relationships) on Lookup relationships as well.

After installing the package, you should be able to define a new Lookup Rollup Summary. In the Lookup Relationship details, as a Parent Object specify **Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c**, Child Object **Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c** again, and the Relationship Field between them (based on information from your trigger) **Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c**. In the Rollup Details section, you should choose **Count** as the Aggregate Operation, **Id** as the Field to Aggregate, and finally the **Total_Child_Agreement__c** as the Aggregate Result Field, ie. as the field where you would like to write the aggregate result values.

Your setup should look something like this:
[image: Lookup Rollup Summary setup for Child record count]

After successful setup, you should deploy the trigger auto generated by the DLRS tool, using ***Manage Child Trigger*** -> ***Deploy*** buttons. After the trigger has been deployed, you should mark your DLRS as Active, save again and that should be it.

For any newly created/edited child agreements, the aggregate count will be properly summarized up to the parent. In order to update the agreements created before the DLRS was set-up, click the ***Calculate*** button, which will start a batch job updating the values on all of the records.